# How to remove ssl certificates from the "trusted root certification authorities" under google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, openssl

I have a self signed wildcard certificate on my localhost *bobslocaldomain.com and it has expired. I want to remove it so I can load a new one.
However I don't seem to be able to remove it. Unlike for other tabs, if you click on any certificate in this tab, the "remove" is grayed out.
For other tabs like "personal" you can remove it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

you're running your browser under low-level permission, run it as administrator..